# python check for numeric value

Tags: python, django, string

I have a form value:

```
anytext = request.POST.get("my_text", None)
if anytext and anytext.is_string:
    perform any action
if anytext and anytext.is_numeric:
    perform another action
```

How can I check for numeric value ??

Comment: You should use a Django form with an IntegerField, then it will validate this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `isdigit()` assuming `anytext` is always of type `string`.

For example:

```
'Hello World'.isdigit()  # returns False
'1234243'.isdigit()  # returns True
```

So with your code:

```
anytext = request.POST.get("my_text", "")
if anytext.isdigit():
    # perform action on numeric string
else:
    # perform action on alphanumeric string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
 if int(re.search(r'\d+', anytext).group())):
    #perform action
```

Comment: This will throw an exception if `anytext` doesn't have a numeric value. You could try `if re.search(r'\d+', anytext):` instead.